# pl/SQL Procedure to generate values in one table from values in a different table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am learning PL/SQL and don't really know where to start writing a procedure.

I have two tables, one with a department name , id ranges from and id ranges to. And another table that needs to have all values in those ranges.

```
-- table_a
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    D_ID number not null primary key,
    DEPT VARCHAR(10),
    ID_FROM VARCHAR(7),
    ID_TO VARCHAR(7),
    IS_POP varchar(1) check(IS_POP IN ('Y', 'N'))
    );

--values in table a
INSERT INTO table_a values (1, 'abc', 'A10', 'A100', 'Y');
INSERT INTO table_a values (2, 'def', 'B10', 'B50', 'N');
INSERT INTO table_a values (3, 'ghi', 'C01', 'C25', 'N');

--table_b
CREATE TABLE table_b (
    D_id number,
    ID_NUM VARCHAR(7) primary key,
    STATUS VARCHAR(8) CHECK (status IN ('Free','Taken')),
    CONSTRAINT fk_interval FOREIGN KEY (D_id) REFERENCES table_a (D_ID)
    );
```

I am trying to write a procedure to populate table_b with values generated  from table_a, where the IS_POP field has 'N', and change it to 'Y' when the values are generated. 
So table_b should have entries with 66 rows of something like

```
D_id ID_NUM STATUS
2     B10   Free
2     B11   Free
2     B12   Free
2     B13   Free
...
3     C24   Free
3     C25   Free
```

Comment: Thanks siretep.  In the example data, the ID_FROM and ID_TO always share the same alphabetic group.  A10 - A100, B10 - B50 etc.  Is this consistent, or are there any cases where the ID_FROM and ID_TO differ in their alphabetic group, like B30 - D-50.

Comment: No, they are the same group. The tables are modified, and I have already wrote a trigger to check for values, and the rules are that the letter in front is the same and the numbers are from smaller to greater values. I also should have stated that  I was thinking to split it with substr and give those values to a for loop. But I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks siretep.  That helps to know.  I added an answer that uses regex value-replacements rather than length/substr (I was not sure about whether the group keys were always single-character or could be multi-character etc.) but if your data is consistent in its format, I believe substr could also be used.

Comment: Thank you alexgibbs. My example was just an example, but the real tables are similar. Now I have an idea where to start. 
Yes, one of the options is that the id_from and id_to values could be updated and the entries that are in table_b shouldn't be lost if there are any in that interval.
About the zero-padding, the only rule is that there are at least 1 and maximum 4 numbers, so i don't really know if A0001 should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example procedure that produces the 66 records in this example data, though I was unsure is some uncertainty about whether the zero-padding is required in `TABLE_B` or not.

This also uses iterative `DML`, so could provide poor performance if used at scale, and it would not be suitable to hand a situation where `TABLE_A` was updated after having already being populated to `TABLE_B`.  These things could be enhanced as required in your situation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE POPULATE_TAB_B
IS
BEGIN
    FOR POINTER IN
        (SELECT D_ID,
             REGEXP_REPLACE(ID_FROM , '[0-9].*' , NULL)             AS PREFIX,
             LEAST(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(ID_FROM , '[^0-9]' , NULL)) ,
                   LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(ID_TO , '[^0-9]' , NULL))) AS PAD_LENGTH,
             TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(ID_FROM , '[^0-9]' , NULL))   AS FROM_NUM,
             TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(ID_TO , '[^0-9]' , NULL))     AS TO_NUM
         FROM TABLE_A
         WHERE TABLE_A.IS_POP = 'N' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT)
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO TABLE_B(D_ID , ID_NUM , STATUS)
            SELECT POINTER.D_ID,
                (POINTER.PREFIX || LPAD(TO_CHAR(((LEVEL - 1) + POINTER.FROM_NUM)) , POINTER.PAD_LENGTH , '0')), 'Free'
            FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ((POINTER.TO_NUM + 1) - POINTER.FROM_NUM);

            UPDATE TABLE_A
            SET TABLE_A.IS_POP = 'Y'
            WHERE TABLE_A.D_ID = POINTER.D_ID;

        END LOOP;

END;
/

Procedure created.

BEGIN
    POPULATE_TAB_B();
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_B
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;

 D_ID ID_NUM   STATUS
     2 B10      Free
     2 B11      Free
     2 B12      Free
     2 B13      Free
...
     3 C08      Free
     3 C09      Free
     3 C10      Free
     3 C11      Free
...
     3 C24      Free
     3 C25      Free
```